# How should I answer the questions in the "Employment and Income" section of a UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-funds, applications

On the "Employment and Income" section of the visa application, the following questions are listed:

1. What is the cost to you personally of your trip in GBP(£)?
2. The total amount of money you have for this trip
3. How much will they [the person paying for my trip] be paying towards your trip (in GBP £)?
4. What is the total amount in GBP(£)?

My Father will be paying for the whole trip for me, so I assume No 3. will be how much he will be paying me - £1,500 I don't need much money because I will be hosted by the friend I am visiting, so I just need money for the flight (£533) and some extra to spend on various non-essential things. Food and accommodation will be free for me).

Also, I assume the total amount (No 4.) will be £1,500 too, because that's the amount of money I'll be spending overall.

**However, is it OK for me to answer No 1 and 2 with £0?**

Comment: I don't know what you are seeing online, but on the paper form this (2) is worded as: "What money is available to you for your trip?"

Comment: @GayotFow So I should answer No 3 & 4 with £1,500 and No 1 & 2 with £0?

Comment: @GayotFow re-reading both your comments my understanding is that 1 should be £0 and 2, 3 and 4 should all be £1,500, correct?
Thanks

Comment: I would advise you to label every monetary value with currency, even when the question specifies the currency, just to be completely unambiguous.  There has been at least one question on this site about a visa refusal that was at least in part based on a misunderstanding of the currency: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62169/uk-visit-visas-refused-due-to-evaluation-oversights-and-similar-errors

Comment: @phoog you can not input special characters such as '£' in the text box on the online application. I'm not sure you can even enter letters in the currency question text boxes.

Comment: @JoelDamien many of the text input elements accept alphabetic characters, if not all of them. I have filled out an online visa application, and I labeled all the currencies that would accept a label using the appropriate three-letter ISO code.  I am quite sure that at least the ones that didn't explicitly ask for GBP accepted these labels. Any values that can't be labeled can be identified in the additional information section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you apply with case when you have your sponsor (father)

1. Can be 0. (or some personal savings.)
2. £1500
   (Long term students {Tier4} if they want to stay in London they need to have at least £1,265 for each month, or £1,015 for each month if they study outside of London. Though this can be less, if they prove with documents that accommodation and food are prepaid, or if they have an invitation and confirmation from their host.)
3. £1500
4. £1500

You should also have questions like: 
If your tickets already paid...

If you going to have a short stay it's better to show prepaid accommodation or an realistic amount to cover an accommodation cost. (As short stay is more expensive than long term Tier 4 students accommodations.) Plus tickets cost or flight confirmations. Plus money for food and for purpose of your stay (shopping, study, traveling).

Based on my own experience of applying for Tier4/study UK visas.

For long term stay we usually show: 1. Paid tickets 2. Paid accommodation for 1 month. 3. Paid studies 4. £1265/£1015 per month. (London/Out of London).

For short stay (less than 1 month) we usually show: 1. Paid tickets 2. Paid accommodation 3. Paid studies or travel program 4. £1265/£1015 (London/Out of London) (It's might be more than required, but better to show more than less.)

---

Seems like my first info was outdated, as I found this:
https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/515465/Tier-_4-_of-the-points-based-system-v36.0.pdf

> Applications submitted on or after 6 April 2012
>
> Study location - Monthly living cost requirement
>
> Inner London - £1,000 per calendar month
>
> Outer London and the rest of the UK - £800 per calendar month
>
> Applications submitted on or after 12 November 2015
>
> Study location - Monthly living cost requirement
>
> In London - £1,265 per calendar month
>
> Outside London - £1,015 per calendar month

page 5.
https://www.britishcouncil.org/sites/default/files/entry-clearance-and-immigration.pdf

> The monthly maintenance requirements state that you must show you have
>   the required sum of money for maintenance in your account for a period
>   of 28 days (£1,000 per month for nine months in inner London and £800
>   per month for outer London or elsewhere in the UK. Up to a maximum of 
>   nine months). This money must take the form of cash funds in the bank
>   (including savings accounts and current accounts, even when notice
>   must be given), a loan letter, or official financial or government
>   sponsorship available to you.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to back up this claim: `If you going to London you need to have £1000 for each month.
Outside of London £800 for each month. ` ?

Comment: £1,000 per month for London is significantly out-of-whack, they will surely refuse an application that aggressive and unrealistic on applicant credibility;  did you make a transcription error? Or using out-of-date information?

Comment: @GayotFow I wish you had told me that before, I put down £1,500 and have already submitted my application, and am about to submit my documents on Thursday. I'll write a cover letter saying £1,500 is just the maximum I'd be spending/my father is willing to pay, and that it includes my air fare (which is £600ish) and include that with my application then... would that be alright? I will be staying for just over 2 weeks and I do intend to do some shopping too.

Comment: The poster above wrote £1,000 per month (less if acco is provided).  That's £33 per day. Compared to 'Lonely Planet's' cheapest estimate of £85 per day, it's ridiculously out-of-whack.  I'm thinking the poster made a transcription error or something like that.  It may not be a show-stopper for your application though

Comment: @GayotFow, oh, so you meant it was too low (thought you meant too high). That's fine then because I'll be taking 1500 GBP for two weeks, outside of London, plus I have free accommodation, so I should be fine, I think. Phew.

Comment: @JoErNanO Just found out that this required for students visas Tier4.

Comment: ViacheslavBakshaev - The numbers you quote seem to be referring to a student, presumably on a student visa. My understanding is that @joelDamien is travelling as a visitor (and possibly for less than a month). The costs are rather different between a toruist and a longer term resident.

Comment: @CMaster you are right!

Comment: I answered as this answer said. 1. as 0 and 2., 3., 4. as £1500.
I got my visa yesterday, flying later tonight. Thank you ALL for your help, I plan on making an article on how I answered all of the questions and what documents I included. Not sure where to post such a thing though.

Comment: @JoelDamien Glad you got your visa! Congratulations! Thanks for coming back and posting your results. Enjoy UK :)