# How do I answer the questions in the “Employment and Income” section of a UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, applications

On the "Employment and Income" section of the visa application, the following questions are listed:

1. **What is the cost to you personally of your trip in GBP(£)?**

(I put it as *£1442.40* as that is the total cost of my trip)

2. **The total amount of money you have for this trip**

(I put it as *£1500* as that is the total money that I will bring for this trip)

3. **Cost of aeroplane, boat or train tickets**

(I put it as *£605* as that is the total money that I have spent for my aeroplane and bus tickets for this trip)

4. **The cost of your accommodation**

(I put it as *£100.45* as that is the total money that will be paid for my pre-booked accommodation)

5. **The cost of your living expenses**

(I put it as *£600* as that is the total money that will be used as living expenses for 6 days in the UK)

6. **How much will they [the person paying for my trip] be paying towards your  trip (in GBP £)?**

(I put it as *£2500* as that is the total money that my father will be sponsoring towards this trip)

7. **What is the total amount in GBP(£)?**

(I am unsure to put either the **total amount that will be spent** or **total money that I will be bringing)**

I am a non-working student, applying for a tourist visa. I have no work, but I have some savings that I will bring for the trip.

In addition, my father will be paying for the whole trip for me, so I assume that **Question #6**. Will be how much he will be paying me, £2500

I am facing problems answering **Question #7**, which is very confusing for me, and I am unsure of how to answer it. I am unsure if it is the **total cost that I will be spending *(incl. total cost of trip, travel tickets, accommodation & living expenses )*** or **the total money that I will be bringing *(incl. the total amount of money you have for this trip & How much will they [the person paying for my trip] be paying towards your trip (in GBP £))***.

I hope that you will be able to help me answer this question, as I have to submit and book an appointment by end of the week as my trip will be in a month

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66279/how-should-i-answer-the-questions-in-the-employment-and-income-section-of-a-uk?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

> What is the total amount in GBP(£)?

This would be the sum of (1) + (6), or in your case, 1,442.40 + 2,500.

> which is very confusing for me, and I am unsure of how to answer it.

The forms can seem vague because they have to cover a lot of different situations. But the questions have been reviewed and nitpicked back-and-forth  both internally in UKVI and externally by members of the UK legal community. They are reviewed twice annually and the one you are currently filling out is in an advanced 'beta' stage.

They are not going to refuse if you interpret the questions differently and compute the sum from some of the other questions. *They are not that captious.*   The main thing they will be looking for is if the cost of the visit map back to the stated premise and the capacities of the applicant and sponsor(s).  They also worry a lot about provenance so be sure your sponsor's funds are adequately sourced.